# Center two images in a div

Tags: css, centering

I have a div like this

```
<div id="browsers">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <p>Text recomending the use of either Chrome or Firefox.</p>
  <a href="http://google.com/chrome/"><img src="img/64-chrome.png" /></a>
  <a href="http://mozilla.org/firefox/"><img src="img/64-firefox.png" /></a>
</div>
```

and the CSS

```
#browsers {
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:22px;
  width:500px;
  background:white;
}
```

and I want to center the two images in the middle of the div. I have managed to center them with

```
#browsers img {
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  display:block;
}
```

however the output is not what I want, since one image is on the top of the other. I want them to be on the same line. What's the best or the usual way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually just `#browsers {text-align:center;}` and remove what you have in `#browsers img {...}`

As you have extra stuff in `#browsers`. You'll need to put your browser icons in a separate `div` or your extra stuff outside of `#browsers`.

Eg.

`<div class="browser-icons"> ... </div>`

Comment: This works quite well. I have read while looking for the answer to my question, however, that [it's not the proper way to do it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055393/css-center-image-using-text-align-center). I'll stick with it for the moment, until somebody gives another option. Thanks!

Comment: @rberaldo: That link says `text-align:center` on the IMG element is not the way to do it, I'm saying to do it on the IMG element's container, not the IMG itself.

Comment: You have a point. I automatically thought it shouldn't be used to center any images _at all_, since it's meant to center text (it's only a guess, but the property is called `*text*-align`, after all).

Comment: Yes, but images are inline elements, so they are inserted into the text, e.g. they will affect the line height when rendered like this.  They can also go inside <a> elements (links) and you cannot have any block level elements inside a link in HTML4, although that is allowed in HTML5 now.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are telling the images are blocks in `display:block;`... try `display:inline;` instead.

Comment: I tried this before, it didn't work. With `display:inline;`, although the icons are in the same line, they're flushed to the left for some reason.