# ER method "image_tag" centered?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods

I have tried to search online for an answer to this question, but to no avail. I'm following Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial, chapter 5, and I went off on my own and made a new view page that uses the method "image_tag." However when I look at the view on localhost:3000 the image is not centered. How can I center the image using "image_tag"?

Answer (score 2):

in Rails 3 you can simply use:

`<%=image_tag("blahblah.png", :align=> "middle")%>`

Comment: @JohnPowel I want the same solution to centered image_tag, but its not working for me. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

`image_tag` is just a helper method to generate a `<img>` tag so you should probably use some CSS to center the image. Take a look a the [API documentation for image_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag)  there is an example of how to add a class attribute to the generated image tag for example.

Comment: I'm pretty new to CSS and HTML. So would I do something like the following to get it centered;

add a code line in the image_tag helper as follows
"""<%=image_tag("blahblah.png", :class => "main_photo")%>"""

and then go to my CSS file and type

"""main_photo {align = center}"""

Comment: Yes something like that. Use the view source function in your browser if you want to see what Rails generates for you. Maybe this questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055393/css-center-image-using-text-align-center can help you with centering the image. Note that you should probably have a dot before "main_photo" to match on class (else you will match on tag name).

Answer (score 1):

In rails 5, I used (with Bootstrap)

```
    <%= link_to image_tag("image.jpg", class: "img-responsive center-block") %>
```