# How to make the element located in the center of a div?

Tags: html, css

I got some images in a div:

```
<div>
    <img src="1.png">  </img>
    <img src="1.png">  </img>
</div>
```

And this in browsers is:

```
-----------------
|XX             |
-----------------
```

and I want to these images to be located in the center of the div, that is to say, like this:

```
-----------------
|      XX       |
-----------------
```

How to do that?

PS: Maybe this question is just very trivial, but I'm a newbie in CSS/HTML and I just can't overcome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS - center image using text-align center?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055393/css-center-image-using-text-align-center)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
div {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Wc8kz/

And only one suggestion: `img` is self-closing tag and should be defined as `<img src="..." />` or even `<img src="...">` in HTML5. Code `<img src="..."></img>` is not valid.

Answer (score 3):

For images, a simple `text-align: center` would suffice.

http://jsfiddle.net/G57zL/1

Answer (score 2):

Right way to do it according to [W3c](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html)

```
img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SC22H/)

Answer (score 1):

**Css**

```
div.centered{
    text-align:center;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="centered">
    <img src="1.png" />
    <img src="1.png" />
</div>
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VAHzv/2/)</kbd>