# Center image in css or html

Tags: html, css, center

I'm trying to center this image on my page, but I have no idea how to do it: http://grab.by/nBca

The code I am using is this:

```
<div class="dronevollelengte">
   <img src="http://www.quirk.be/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/drakdrone.jpg"
        text-align: center/>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS - center image using text-align center?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055393/css-center-image-using-text-align-center)

Answer (score 9):

You need to put the `text-align: center` part in a style attribute, for the div. You can't simply throw it in the HTML outside of an attribute.

```
<div class="dronevollelengte" style="text-align: center"><img src="http://www.quirk.be/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/drakdrone.jpg" /></div>
```

OR, use that in a CSS file and attach it to the class:

```
.dronevollelengte {
    text-align: center; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately I still have the same issue. I have cleaned up my code and made it in to this: '<div class="dronevollelengte" style="position: absolute;"><img src="img"/></div>

Comment: Why the `position:absolute`? It's causing the div to go outside the document flow. Also, it makes it width-less, it will fit whatever is inside. So there's nothing to center in.

Comment: The div is probably for the image only so you could style the div with auto left and right margin. It will not work with the position absolute though...

Comment: Thanks @Brainfeeder What I want to do is to make my image fill the entire width of my screen. The template has a fixed width, but by using position:absolute it can extend beyond those borders.

Do you haven any alternative solutions?

Comment: if you know the width of the image, then `position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -???px` would be your solution, `???` being **1/2** the image width

Comment: Thank you @ChenAsraf for your answer. What I want to do is this: http://www.polygon.com/e3-2013/2013/6/14/4429254/the-division-massive
You can see the image filling the entire width. Is this the best way to do it or do you have an alternative suggestion?

Comment: An alternative, if you're talking about the header area, is to make a div that's outside the fixed width part of the template, and manipulate it there. I'd also say use a background image and not an `<img />` tag for this case, for extra customizability in the future. Either way, it's either that or the solution with the margin and position

Comment: Thanks it worked like a charm, @ChenAsraf The thing that made it work was setting left tot 0% instead of 50%. The only problem I have now is that a part of the bottom doesn't show on desktop. It does on mobile though. I tried fixing that by using the same technique for the bottom area, but that didn't work. Any tips?

Comment: You mean the image is cut at the bottom?

Comment: Probably because `position: absolute` removes it from the document flow, causing it to not enlarge the height of the document as it goes lower. You should make a div of the image's height, right after the image, which will 'save' that space for the image http://jsfiddle.net/OhMrBigshot/n3Htw/

Comment: I inserted this in my css. Should I add anything?
`code`.dronevollelengte {
position: absolute;
left: 0%;
margin-left: -3000px;
margin:0 auto;
width: 100% !important;
height: 1673px;
}`code`

Comment: I've managed to do it, but the problem now is, that it fills the entire page section: http://grab.by/nBjE

Answer (score -1):

You could style the div instead.
In your CSS add this:

```
.dronevollelengte {
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

This sets the top and bottom `margin` to 0 and the left and right `margin` to auto... This will center the `div`. So it would be wise to provide a `width`for it.

check [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8R23A/) for a working example.

Comment: Mhh, I used width="100%" but to no avail. Thank you for your help though. Not sure why the image extends all the way to the right, but not to the left.