# arrange many blocks at the center (html)

Tags: html, css, block

This is my code.

```
<html>

<head><title>HOME||~All About EDM~</title>


</head>

<body >
<center><img src="edm1.jpg" alt="edm" width="950" height="250"></body></center>

<center>
<style type="text/css" >
ul
{
list-style-type:none;

margin:0;
padding:0;
overflow:hidden;
}
li
{
position:relative;
    left:18%;
float:left;
}
a:link,a:visited
{


display:block;
width:200px;
font-weight:bold;
color:#272525;
background-color:#DF01A5;
text-align:center;
padding:10px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
a:hover,a:active
{
background-color:#272525;
font-weight:bold;
color:#DF01A5;
text-align:center;
}

</style>
</center>

<center>
<ul>
<li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="genres.html">Genres</a></li>
<li><a href="photos.html">Photos</a></li>
<li><a href="info.html">Info</a></li>

</center>

</body>
</html>
```

There are 5 blocks (in a row) that are supposed to be arranged in the center of it but i have no idea how to do that. I tried some different ways but it gets in the center as a collumn, not as a row.

Comment: Add your HTML as well.

Comment: <html>
<body>
<center><img src="edm1.jpg" alt="edm" width="950" height="250"></body></center>

<head><title>HOME||~All About EDM~</title>

Comment: Are you aware that your HTML is invalid?

Comment: It is called `head` for a reason.

Comment: a:link,a:visited have a missing t in the text-decoration:none; property as well.

Comment: Your HTML is a mess. You have closed the `body` tag before closing the `center` tag, and the `head` needs to be above the `body` just like my head needs to be above my body. Also where is the rest of you code?

Comment: Where is your style being applied? Do you have a <style> tag or is it in an external style sheet?

Comment: You are closing body tag twice

Comment: ok forget that i didnt see it. i fixed it and still cant get that working

Answer (score 0):

What about this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayVEb/)

Normal structure is:

```
<head>
<title>HOME||~All About EDM~</title>

<style type="text/css"></style>
</head>

<body>
<img src="edm1.jpg" alt="edm" width="950" height="250">


<ul>
<li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="genres.html">Genres</a></li>
<li><a href="photos.html">Photos</a></li>
<li><a href="info.html">Info</a></li>
</ul>


</body>
</html>
```

Also don't forget to add a doctype.

Answer (score 0):

The center tag is not supported in HTML5. You'll want to center it with your CSS instead with text-align: center;.

```
<div class = 'imgClass'>
    <img src="edm1.jpg" alt="edm" width="950" height="250">
</div>
```

...

```
.imgClass {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: To center align the image you need to apply the text-align property on the parent element. Floating the img does work though.

Answer (score 0):

Text-align is not the recommended way to center images (see [Center image using text-align center?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055393/center-image-using-text-align-center))

You want to either define a specific width for the div or set it's display type to "block" (which you have), and set margin-left and margin-right to "auto", as the answer in the post indicates.

Comment: There is no need for putting margin-left and margin-right seperately. You can just do margin:auto;