# How to center images

Tags: image, containers, margin, center

I have put the body of my page in a container. I then put my images in a div and gave them the class 'grid_12' and id 'gallery'. Here is the CSS i wrote for that id.

`#gallery img{`

```
border: 8px solid;
color: #0000FF;
margin: 0 0 20px 0;
```

}

What code do i need to center the images? I've already unsuccessfully tried floating-center/text-align-center.

Comment: You could try `margin: 0 auto;` and set the padding at 20px instead of the margin.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
img.center {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

}

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055393/center-image-using-text-align-center)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to give the size of div (width and height) then try your css code...