# How to Center a Image Shape in CSS

Tags: css

I am brand new to CSS and am using [this tutorial](http://bavotasan.com/2011/circular-images-with-css3/) to make an image circular. But I cannot for the life of me figure out how to center the image on my website. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Nvm here is [a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055393/center-image-using-text-align-center) to solve the issue.

Comment: here you go http://jsfiddle.net/x287c/

Answer (score 0):

Html COde

```
<center><div class="circleBase demo"></div></center>
```

css Code

```
.circleBase {
    border-radius: 50%;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc); /* remove if you don't care about IE8 */
}

.demo {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: Blue;
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```

Comment: `<center>` has been deprecated for a very long time.