# CSS Margin: 0 Auto; is not working on <img> tag

Tags: html, css, margin

My markup is simple, and I'm using inline CSS.  My goal is to get the image centered using `margin: 0 auto;` in the `style` HTML attribute.  Here's code that I have tried:

```html
<div style="width: 100%;">
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x300/000000/fff" style="margin: 0 auto;"/>
</div>
```

Why is the CSS not centering my `<img>`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You must use `display: block` to make `margin: 0px auto` have any effect.

```html
<div style="width: 100%;">
<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" style="display: block; margin: 0px auto;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your style attribute syntax is wrong on the div.  Also, change the style on the img tag like so:

```
<div style="width:100%">
<img src="https://4c206b86fe5a0219d31bb1ae55c8bbdc3f028879-www.googledrive.com/host/0BzEiAml5ygAeU3N6QTRUUW53Vjg/" width="50%" height="auto" style="margin:0 auto; display:block">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`Img` is an inline element, so `width: 0 auto` won't work, unless you set `display: block`. Or you can center it with `text-align: center`, which is a bit weird, but should work similarly.

Also, you should consider stop using inline styles. It makes html markup harder to read, harder to maintain etc. Styles belong to separate css files and you should try to avoid inline styles whenever possible. (and html attributes like width, height etc AS WELL!)

Well, and also `margin-left:0 auto; margin-right:0 auto;` isn't really valid. The correct form would be either

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

or

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

Comment: "width: 0 auto" - did you mean margin: 0 auto?

Answer (score 0):

```
text-align: center;
```

On image tags seems not to be w3c valid anyway.

```
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
```

Should be!

[Considering this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055393/center-image-using-text-align-center)

Comment: text-align: center only centers an image if it's applied to the image's parent.