# Embedding video at the center of the image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align the video to the center of the image.

```css
.vbackground {
  background-image: url('http://s1.postimg.org/hdo0xh2of/image.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
}
#match {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='vbackground'>
  <video controls id='match' width='300' height='300'>
    <source src='match.mp4' type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
</div>
```

How could I make the video at the center of the image (from all sides)? It currently gets aligned at the bottom of the image.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `position: absolute` rule from the `match` id selector and set the `text-align` property on the `.vbackground` class to `center`.
This should work -

```
.vbackground {
    background-image: url('http://s1.postimg.org/hdo0xh2of/image.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
 }    
 #match {
    /*position: absolute;*/
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Just realized that using the `text-align: center;` rule for positioning an image is not recommended (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055393/center-image-using-text-align-center?rq=1). You could instead, set the width and height of .vbackground to the original image's size, i.e. 594px/372px respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Just add  `margin-left:auto` and  `margin-right: auto`; to your `#match` CSS STYLE and it will align the video to the center of the image.

```css
 
#match {

  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;

}
```