# Vertical align image in center div

Tags: html, css

I would like to vertical align a image in the center of a div.

For this I use this code:

```
<div id="cboxLoadedContent" style="width: 1024px; overflow: auto; height: 738px; vertical-align: middle;">
    <img class="cboxPhoto" src="" style="cursor: pointer; float: none; width: 50%; vertical-align: middle;"></img>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3uk642wg/

How can I achieve that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Center image using text-align center?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055393/center-image-using-text-align-center)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
div#cboxLoadedContent {
   .... 
   display: table-cell;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/3uk642wg/1/

```css
div#cboxLoadedContent {border: 1px solid #333; display: inline-block;text-align: center; display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;}
.cboxPhoto {vertical-align: middle;}
```

```html
<div id="cboxLoadedContent" style="width: 1024px; overflow: auto; height: 738px; vertical-align: middle;">
<img class="cboxPhoto" src="https://www.google.com//images/srpr/logo11w.png" style="cursor: pointer; float: none; width: 50%; vertical-align: middle;"></img>
</div>
```

Comment: I totally missed aligning vertically! Good answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this on modern browsers you can try this.

```
div#cboxLoadedContent {
border: 1px solid #333; 
display: inline-block; 
text-align: center;
}
.cboxPhoto {
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```