# Making a navigation logo position in center

Tags: html, css

I have this code inside a grid.

```
<div class="nav__logo nav__logo--height">  
  <a href="http://localhost/step-asia/">
    <img src="assets/image/logo-1.png" alt="Step Asia Logo">
  </a>
</div>
```

and this is the css style

```
.nav__logo {
  border: 1px solid #f7b5b5;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav__logo a {
  display: table;
  color: black;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav__logo--height {
  height: 19px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
.nav__logo img {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I tried using **position** property but its not the solution, there's a problem using it when resizing the screen. **text-align** doesn't works also since it's an image.

The DIV above is inside a grid column.
Can you give an idea. Revising the code is acceptable, just need idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Center image using text-align center?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055393/center-image-using-text-align-center)

Comment: No. The link you give for possible duplicate, is not same with the problem I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use flex layout for container element

```
.nav__logo{
   border: 1px solid #f7b5b5;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   flex-wrap: nowrap;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items:center;
   align-content:  center;
}
.nav__logo--height {
  height: 19px;
  width: 100%;
}
.nav__logo>a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav__logo>img {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: @Fil it is used for responsive and centralized elements

Answer (score 1):

Hello hope it helps use the below code  I used  css `justify-content: center;` to move the  navigation logo center

```css
.nav__logo {
  border: 1px solid #f7b5b5;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="nav__logo nav__logo--height">  
  <a href="http://localhost/step-asia/">
    <img src="http://quesa.sourceforge.net/other/files/logo_small.jpg" alt="Step Asia Logo">
  </a>
</div>
  </body
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by 
`.nav__logo a {
  display: table;`

you want to change that to `display: inline;` or `display:block;` or `display: inline-block`

pretty much "table" is the only value that wont do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `text-align:center` in your `a` tag so that the image will be in center.

```
.nav__logo a {
  display: table;
  color: black;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Here is an example **[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r83y9o9r/)**

Answer (score 0):

To center the image remove `display: table;` from a tag or make it `display: inline-block;`

```
.nav__logo {
  border: 1px solid #f7b5b5;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav__logo a {
  color: black;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav__logo--height {
  height: 19px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
.nav__logo img {
  margin: 0 auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.nav__logo {
border: 1px solid #f7b5b5;  
position: absolute;
top: calc(50% - 96px);/*image height*/
left: calc(50% - 284px);/*image width*/
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="nav__logo nav__logo--height">  
<a href="http://localhost/step-asia/">
<img src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_284x96dp.png" alt="Step Asia Logo">
</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```