# To print image in center by Perl cgi HTML

Tags: html, image, perl, cgi

i want to ask how to print my image in center by using perl cgi 
here is my code :

```
print img({src=>"/image.png",width=>"200px",hight=>"100px"}),
```

i tried:

```
print img({-align=>CENTER}, {src=>"/image.png",width=>"200px",hight=>"100px"}),
```

but it's not working

Comment: "it's not working" is not exactly helpful. Have you read the stackoverflow's help pages on how to ask a question?

Comment: You wrote `hight` instead of `height`. I don't know whether it solves your problem.

Comment: Not that I want to encourage you to continue using this very outdated style of HTML and means of generating it, but shouldn't the align bit go into the same hash reference as everything else

Comment: @ChrisTurner You are correct, it should - plus `CENTER` should be in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a HTML/CSS question. See [Center image using text-align center?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7055404/9300627) - applying that here:

```
print img({style=>"display:block;margin: 0 auto;",
    src=>"/image.png",width=>"200px",height=>"100px"});
```

Or use a CSS class and put `class=>"classname"` in the hashref instead of `style`.