# To align fieldset tag in html

Tags: html, css

How to align text and images inside  tag in the middle?

```
<html>
<head>
<body bgcolor = "lavender">
<fieldset style="border-color:blue;">
 <img id="image1" src="bed.jpg" height=250 width=250>
 <img id="image2" src="bed.jpg" height=250 width=250>
<img id="image3" src="bed.jpg" height=250 width=250>
<img id="image4" src="bed.jpg" height=250 width=250>
<img id="image5" src="bed.jpg" height=250 width=250>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: maybe text-align:center ?

Comment: _Align_ In what way?

Comment: What have you tried, show us your CSS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Center image using text-align center?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055393/center-image-using-text-align-center)

Comment: Where is text in this example?

Answer (score 0):

```css
img {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
height:250px;
width:250px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset style="border-color:blue;">
<img id="image1" src="bed.jpg">
<img id="image2" src="bed.jpg">
<img id="image3" src="bed.jpg">
<img id="image4" src="bed.jpg">
<img id="image5" src="bed.jpg">
</fieldset>
```

Is this what you want?