# Center images in a <section>

Tags: html, image, fullscreen, center

I have a `<section>` tag in which there are 3 images. How can I center them for fullscreens?
The size of my screen is 22.9 ".
here is the code:

```
    <section class="gallery">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="fw mix-container home-gallery">
        <div class="mix landscape portrait">
          <div class="item-img">
             <img src="images/parfum-aux-agrumes-002.jpg""/>
          </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="mix landscape portrait">
          <div class="item-img">
             <img src="images/parfum-aux-agrumes-003.jpg""/>
          </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="mix landscape portrait">
          <div class="item-img">
             <img src="images/parfum-aux-agrumes-004.jpg""/>
          </div>
        </div>        
    </div>  
  </div> 
</div>
```

Thank you for your answers
Best regards.

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/7055404/2544873 ? Which advices : `<img style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;" src="images/parfum-aux-agrumes-004.jpg"/>`. I just added the style.

Comment: Hello, I have now altered my answer below, - i think i did miss a line of code out before, sorry for any confusion

Answer (score 0):

I have included a code snippet below that will run.

Essentially you make the images inline-block so they sit next to each other.
Then you can set the images parent container to be left 50%, and offset it with *transform:translate();*

You can change the width of the images as needed but the same logic should still apply.

```css
.mix {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: black solid 1px;
  display: inline-block;
}  

.mix-container {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

```html
 <section class="gallery">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="fw mix-container home-gallery">
        <div class="mix landscape portrait">
          <div class="item-img">
             <img src="images/parfum-aux-agrumes-002.jpg"/>
          </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="mix landscape portrait">
          <div class="item-img">
             <img src="images/parfum-aux-agrumes-003.jpg"/>
          </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="mix landscape portrait">
          <div class="item-img">
             <img src="images/parfum-aux-agrumes-004.jpg"/>
          </div>
        </div>        
    </div>  
  </div> 
</div>  
</section>
```