# How to center an image on React

Tags: html, css

Apologies because this is kind of a simple question, but I have tried a lot of things but still cannot find the solution to center this image: className="meme--image"
I just want that image to be in the center of the page.

Here is my CSS code:

```
.form {
    gap: 20px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template: 40px 40px  / 1fr 1fr;
}

.form--submit {
    grid-column: 1/ -1;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #672280 1.18%, #A626D3 100%);
    color: white;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: "Karla", sans-serif;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.form--input {
    border: 1px solid #D5D4D8;
    border-radius: 0.3125rem;
    font-family: inherit;
    text-indent: 5px;
}
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
export default function Input() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="form">
                <input type="text" className="form--input" placeholder="Top text" />
                <input type="text" className="form--input" placeholder="Bottom text" />
                <button className="form--submit" onClick={getMemeImage}> Get a new meme image </button>
            </div>
            <img src="https://i.imgflip.com/3lmzyx.jpg"className="meme--image" />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Center image using text-align center?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055393/center-image-using-text-align-center)

Answer (score 0):

just give image some height width and make margin auto.

```
.meme--image{
   width:400px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a div wrapper for `img` element with class as `image-container` and with the following styles.

```html
<div className="image-container">
     <img src="https://i.imgflip.com/3lmzyx.jpg" className="meme--image" />
</div>
```

```css
.image-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 150px);
}
```

Deduction of `150px` in height is for the space to the top section.

[image: Edit hopeful-mestorf-z0xs2]

[image]

Comment: @22bash, check this out !!